# Finding the region of convergence of $\sum{\frac{a^n}{(x^n+a^n)}} $, where $a$ is fixed

Tags: sequences-and-series

Apply tests to find its regions of convergence and divergence.

None of the tests I know seems to work.

Comment: First, try to learn the easy rules to properly write mathematics in this site. Second, as it appears I don't think your question makes much sense: what is $\;a_n\;\;,\;\;x_n\;$ , or $\;a_n\;,\;\;x^n\;$, or whatever, to begin with??

Comment: Sorry for that. It's fixed now.

Comment: $a$ is a fixed parameter ? Or $x$ is a fixed parameter ?

Comment: $a$ is a constant

Comment: If a series is to converge, it is necessary for all the terms to converge to zero.   $\left( \frac{a^n}{x^n + a^n} \right) = \left( \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^n}\right)$, so start with $|x| > a$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for $\;|x|\le|a|\;$ we have that

$$b_n:=\frac{a^n}{a^n+x^n}=\frac1{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^n}\rlap{\;\;\;/}\longrightarrow 0$$

and thus the series cannot converge, so we can assume now that $\;|x|>|a|\;$ , and then

$$\sqrt[n]{|b_n|}=\frac1{\sqrt{\left|1+\left(\frac xa\right)^n\right|}}\le\frac1{\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac xa\right|^n}}\le\left|\frac ax\right|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\left|\frac ax\right|<1$$

and thus the series *always* converges in this case

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\dfrac{a^n}{x^n+a^n}.$

If $\left|\dfrac{a}{x}\right|\lt1$ then $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty.$
Otherwise $a_n\not\to 0.$

Apply the ratio test for convergence of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n$ with $|a|\lt|x|.$